# Building ambience 

Tags: ambience, tutorial

Are there any good tutorials videos that can help me build ambience and a whole environment .

Thanx

Comment: If possible, please provide a more detailed revision to your question.  At the moment it is far too broad I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any tutorial but here are my two cents, for what it is worth.

There are many things to consider when creating ambience for a scene. Obvious things like geographic location, weather, time period, time of day, interior, exterior,and of course film or TV genre. Finding the right size tracks, whether that means the size of your tone, crowd, waves or traffic etc also help to sell a realistic scene.

You also need to consider the story, what can you do to support it. Is it a tense moment? maybe pulling back some sounds to keep the focus on the dialogue helps, or, maybe a rising discordant tone will draw the viewer in. Is it happy, pretty sounds like birds, although cliche, help ease the moment. A seedy neighborhood may have rougher sounds like sirens, or cars with bad mufflers.

Helping to match, or mask a noisy or great sounding production track through critical listening is also appreciated and helps your Ambience tracks move away from being just tracks to creating a realistic environment.

Rarely can you find one track to sell a scene. Using multiple layers of sounds, in different frequency spectrums, and specific one off sounds can create new and exciting scenes.

Finding the sounds that feel right and fit take time and experience, but you will get there if it is important to you. Watching and listening to alot of films and TV series of different genres will give you some great ideas to start with.
I personally love the Ambience in Film and TV, and feel that when it is done well that it can really en-richen a viewers experience, even if only on a sub-concious level.